# Can we use Azure Data Migration Service to migrate data from on-prem SQL Server to Azure SQL DW

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I wanted to understand if we can use Azure Data Migration Service to migrate data from on-prem SQL Server to Azure SQL DW or is there any other way to do so which also takes care of full and incremental load?

Thanks,

Anish

Comment: Please note that SQL DW (now christened as Synapse) is not a regular SQL SMP architecture. This is an MPP database and hence as-is migration of on-prem SQL boxes to SQL DW may not always be a good choice. What is the use case for this migration?

Comment: Our organization is planning to move to Azure and since the data size is more than 1 TB and increasing, Azure SQL DW is selected. I was exploring migration techniques but didn't find any for the same. @RaunakJhawar can you suggest me some sites where in I can go through the migration for such an architecture. That would be very helpful of you.

Comment: Note that SQL DB (especially Gen5) can grow up to 8TB and with hyper-scale edition, this can go up to 100TB. Have you also considered these facts before choosing SQL DW? A lot of information is available on documentation online. In case you are solving a specific problem please create a new thread on SO.

Comment: Hi Anish, glad if you can mark the below note as answered so that points can be credited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that SQL DW (now christened as Synapse) is not a regular SQL SMP architecture. This is an MPP database and hence as-is migration of on-prem SQL boxes to SQL DW may not always be a good choice.

Note that SQL DB (especially Gen5) can grow up to 8TB and with hyper-scale edition, this can go up to 100TB. Have you also considered these facts before choosing SQL DW? A lot of information is available on documentation online.